# Python schedule a job at specific time

Tags: python, twitter, schedule

Is there any way to have a script with python that schedule a a job on a given datetime? For instance schedule a tweet at `01-09-2017 09:30:00`.

So far I have seen the *schedule* and *apscheduler* libraries but I haven't find that allows me to schedule at a given time only for once.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to send something just once right?

Comment: You can look into `celery`.

Comment: @NickChapman That's correct

Comment: @vishes_shell I toke a look to the docu of 'celery' but so far I haven't seen any fuction that has a datetime as input. Do you know any in specific?

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: schedule a tweet at 01-09-2017 09:30:00.

Simple Solution, for example:

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    starttime = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 1, hour=9, minute=30, second=0)
    while True:
        if datetime.today() > starttime:
            break
        time.sleep(60)

    main()
```